# Windows Advanced Security Settings with absent users

Tags: windows, windows-7

When trying to set permissions on files or folders, the "Select Users or Groups" window opened any security window (eg: "Advanced Security Settings") always fails to find, and let me add, a known local user.

In the "Local Users and Groups" (Computer=>Manage), the user exists in "Users" (and belongs to groups Administrators and "HomeUsers")

If I try to add a group to an existing user ("Add" => "Advanced" => "Find Now") I get also Unspecified error.

[image: arggg]

If I try to create a user directly from the "Local Users and Groups" I also get "Unspecified error" (but not from control panel), but then the user seems created when I reopen "Local Users and Groups". When I then try to delete this user I get "An invalid directory pathname was passed"

I can google anything relevant on the subject.

Windows 7 Pro, no active domain, user is active (visible via cmd "net user")

This seemed to work a couple months back with my fresh install, since then I only updated Windows with all Windows Updates.

Comment: While I have absolutely no idea what causes this, it does not look like something trivial. Consider running **sfc /scannow** and if that does not work, reinstalling Windows 7.

Comment: Reinstalling Windows is the last thing I would want to do. Reinstalling any OS is usually last resort only.

Comment: "*Reinstalling any OS is usually last resort only.*" In a generalized and well maintained environment reinstalling a client OS takes 30 minutes and is the first thing I do when troubleshooting would take longer than two hours. So use the term "*usually*" with caution. But … I cannot talk for your environment, though. Maybe that is something that can be improved? – Okay, enough talking off-topic for me, I'll leave you alone now. 

Comment: @Daniel "In a generalized and well maintained environment", you're talking about a company with pre-built images. This is not the case.

If this was a Linux, I'ld already have reinstalled it. But Windows is just a pain for reinstalling software, restoring preferences and all the likes. Let's say I keep my AppLocal and HKEY_CURRENT_USER. Who's to say that the problem isn't located in either that folder or that registry key?